# UIAccessibility -Voice over not working for a NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a Text "The User can make changes 'here'." the letter "here" is clickable , and on tap of it.[Check the image][1]

The default voice over is not focusing on it and not reading it out.

How can i make it focus with voice over ,make it clickable and pronounce the name.

Created a extension for UI Label and Am calculating attributedText frame from NSRange.

```
        let attribute : [String : Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Theme.getColor(forCode: "LinkBlue")]
        let strToUse = contentForKey("String")
        range =  (footerText as NSString).range(of: strToUse)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: footerText)
        if let textRange = range{
             attributedString.addAttributes(attribute, range:textRange)
        }
        footerVw.headerTitleLabel.attributedText = attributedString
        footerVw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyProfileViewController.showPage))
        footerVw.headerTitleLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

> Thanks in advance.
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLQZF.png

Comment: This code snippet is not enough, there is a lot of contextual information that is missing.  What is footerVw? Does any of this view ever get focused by VoiceOver?  Etc.

Comment: Yes its gets focused. Its focusing on the whole label(including "here"). i want it to be focused separately and read

Comment: You should create two separate UILabels (or perhaps a UILabel and a UIButton), and style them similarly and line them up together.

Comment: From an accessibility point of view, having the whole view be actionable is probably preferable.

Comment: did so, but it violates the Ux design

Comment: UX Design?  Only users with disabilities are going to experience what it means to have VoiceOver focus.  And separating out an element that just says "here" is very much not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Things that make a view independently focusable by VoiceOver:

- `theView.isAccessibilityElement = true`
- `allHeirarchicalParentViews.isAccessibilityElement = false`

OR

- `hierarchicalParent.isAccessibilityElement = false`
- `hierarchicalParent` implements the `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol.

If you were to give more detail on how this view is implemented, particularly what the exact separation between 'The user can now make changes' and 'here' is, we could provide a more precise answer.  EX: What types of views your dealing with, what type of layout view, are the views that contain those different bits of text separate, or is it just the string that is attributed, what element is it that is active and how... etc?

Let's assume we just want the whole UILabel to represent the focusable area, and the entire thing is active (scenario 1). There's going to be a simple issue with this solution. When VoiceOver activates accessibilityElements, the activation point is the middle of the focused rectangle.  So, let's assume that your UILabel has some type of click listener on it, and the whole bit of text is encompassed by VoiceOver focus. You want to set the `accessibilityActivationPoint` to be where the "here" text is.

```
yourUILabel.accessibilityActivationPoint = calculatePointOf(text:'Here')
```

Comment: Created a extension for UI Label and Am calculating attributedText frame from NSRange.

Comment: You should separate them into two different objects. One informative and one active.  Or just let the entire UILabel be active.  Either way. But, the answer to that is the answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

> The default voice over is not focusing on it and not reading it out.

A good way to reach your goal is to **wrap your mutable string inside a `UITextView`** whose delegate will allow to open as many links as wanted: **you won't achieve your purpose with a single `UILabel`**.

Assuming that you're working with a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, try and add this wrapper in your footer `contentView` for instance.

> How can I make it focus with voice over, make it clickable and pronounce the name.

That's a **[specific VoiceOver gesture](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html#OpenLink)** that activates the selected link: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957871/3825084) that contains a complete example including illustrations to see how focus and activation work.