# How to get accessibility to recognize two hyperlinks in one UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uitextview, accessibility

When using accessibility with my UITextView that contains two separate hyperlinks, VoiceOver only reads out the first of the two hyperlinks and only lets you double tap to access that one. Is there a way to distinguish between the two for both VoiceOver and access through double taps?

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957871/3825084

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue today.
When UITextView is not editable, the  rotor link gesture mode not working; you should set the UITextView editable and follow the [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957871/3825084), this will work

Answer (score 0):

I found some kind of workaround: put a \n at the start of each string with link attribute. The text will be unformatted with the new jump line but each line touched will work again.