# UIAccessibilityElement focusing issue within a long view inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, voiceover

I have a `UITableViewCell` containing a view which has some child accessibility elements. The view is quite long, longer that a single screen.

When user flicks left and right to navigate through the child elements, the selected element is out of screen sometimes. When he double taps later he cannot trigger the action for such an element.

Why does it not work? How to make it work correctly?

Why is the selected element out of screen sometimes? How to make it in screen?

Here is the [sample code](https://mega.nz/#!4H4FkYhS!0mQhoc5MGG3HbAfGm-VDBj-cqLAg8P4cne8AJiHPfxs).

1. When double tap works correctly you will see a log in Xcode console.
2. It is an over simplified sample. I cannot use separate cells in the real app. Think of it as a rich text view with links, and users use left and right flick to select links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it not work? How to make it work correctly?

With **VoiceOver OFF** ❌, the `tap` function prints the element once you touch it **AND** if it's visible because a tap gesture only happens on screen.

With **VoiceOver ON** ✅, you should think the same way even if the screen reader is able to read out the previous labels that are out of screen: when you double-tap with one finger for an element out of screen, the gesture can't be handled with a `GestureRecognizer`.
A solution could be the use of the [accessibilityActivate](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#DefaultActivation) method that's triggered when a double-tap occurs on a a11y element.

I suggest to create a label class in which you implement this function:

```
class myLabel:UILabel {

    init(frame: CGRect, index: Int) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        text = "\(index)"
        isAccessibilityElement = true
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap)))
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {
        print(text!)
        return true
    }

    @objc func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        guard sender.state == .recognized else { return }
        print(sender.view!)
    }
}
```

The `LongView` class has the following code to define its behavior:

```
class LongView: UIView {

    override var isAccessibilityElement: Bool {
        get { return false }
        set {   }
    }

    override var accessibilityElementsHidden: Bool {
        get { return false }
        set {   }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        var x: CGFloat = 20
        var y: CGFloat = 20
        let width: CGFloat = 200
        let height: CGFloat = 40
        let spacing: CGFloat = 20

        for index in 0..<20 {

            let label = myLabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height),
                                index: index)
            addSubview(label)

            x += width + spacing
            if x + width > screenWidth {
                y += height + spacing
                x = spacing
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

        CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
               height: subviews.map { $0.frame.maxY }.max()! + 20)
    }
}
```

And the table view cell class is as follows:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let longView = LongView()

        longView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
        contentView.addSubview(longView)

        longView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        longView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        longView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        longView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        longView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}
```

Now, you can notice that:

- The `GestureRecognizer` function will be triggered when VoiceOver is OFF.
- The one finger double-tap gesture will be handled when VoiceOver is ON on every single label that is present on screen or not.

I'm not sure that all the added lines are necessary to reach your goal but this is the **rationale to solve your UIAccessibilityElement focusing issue within a long view inside a UITableViewCell**.

Comment: The `accessibilityActivate` trick works, thanks! However, I'm still having some other issues related to selected element not being in screen. Do you why the selected element is out of screen sometimes? How to make it in screen?

Comment: @an0: I asked the behavior you wished before providing information and you pointed out the problem dealing with the double-tap I answered. Then, you edited your question by adding other requirements : please, create another question with an accurate title for this dedicated goal otherwise it's endless. 

Comment: But the post will be 95% the same, with the exactly same sample code. Probably will be marked as duplicate. Also, I pointed out that the double tap doesn't work because the element is out of screen, but I admit that I didn't make it clear that when I say "why does it not work" I mean why the element is out of screen. I'll accept your answer. If you know the answer to the root issue, I'll appreciate if you can add it here. Thanks again.

Comment: @an0: I don't know the solution of this problem but would have taken time searching if it was the main problem you wanted to solve as I did for the double-tap I didn't know either.  At first sight, it may be due to the view you use to insert the labels because it's too high for a single cell and one should find out a way to say: 'display the cell content from the top and not the bottom if it's higher than the screen'. 

Comment: @an0: if you want to insert rich text with links inside the table view cell allowing users to select them with left and right flick, I strongly suggest to remove the 'LongView' and add an attributed string with links that can be more easily handled with VoiceOver than with this architecture choice in my view ⟹ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957871/3825084

Comment: Yes, I believe out-of-screen element is a root cause of some other issues in my app. Is there a way to control `UITableView.contentOffset` when user flicks to an element? That could be a solution if possible. As to link attributed string, no all the elements are links, and the interaction looks much more convoluted.

Comment: @an0: I would take a look at the `UIAccessibilityFocus` informal protocol if I wanted to use the `contentOffset` when an a11y element is selected ⇒ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element 